# what is excel alternative function for indirect used to reference another sheet

Tags: excel, office365

**Context**: im working on 300 contracts and making data bank from those contract infos. contracts are in sheets named like 001, 001 (2), 002, 003 like
i did print sheets name using "name manager" refers to: `=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")`
and `=index(Sheetname,A2)` in A column its numbers 1to 300

**Problem im facing**: i used indirect function `=INDIRECT("'"&$B2&"'!$C$4")` to call contracts name... etc. but after 300 this excel load too much i did some sumifs on those infos but calculate every little change.

How to call those info in databank from sheet or how to change indirect function to other non volatile function.

i tried concat, index but no result value or na.
`=vlookup(CONCAT("'",B2,"'",C4) VLOOKUP(F$2,'(INDEX(SheetNernuud,B2)'!$B$3:$C$12,2)`
it bear no friut.

Comment: `INDEX()` must work if you refer sheet name.

Comment: @Harun24hr how its should be writing? for example 
B2 is sheets name like 001, and i want =INDEX('001'!B3:C24,2,2) which calling contractors name. how should i write index with B2 cell? and so on B columns

Comment: i tried =INDEX(B2!$B$3:$C$24,2,2). 
=index('B2'!$B$3:$C$24  and B2&!$B$3:$C$24. those all not working

Comment: @In that case only option is using `INDIRECT()`.

Comment: So work in blocks of 10 for example and once they have resolved then copy paste.special values so they become text. Then do the next 10 etc

Comment: @Harun24hr ooh its sad, okey thanks.

Comment: @SolarMike ooh thats sure work but my case is we want it somehow automated when contract get cancelled or some date and other things changed i want to display in this one summary. thanks

Comment: @ike thank you for edit it looks so much better and easy to understand. is there way to handle this using VBA? (i know nothing about VBA wizardry)

Comment: So, are you basically trying to extract the value in cell C4 of all you sheet?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract a single cell form each sheet, try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubReport()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim WksSheet As Worksheet
    Dim StrAddress As String
    Dim VarReport() As Variant
    
    'Settings.
    ReDim VarReport(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
    StrAddress = "C4"
    VarReport(1, 1) = "Sheet"
    VarReport(2, 1) = "Value in " & StrAddress(0, 0)
    
    'Covering each worksheet in ThisWorkbook.
    For Each WksSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        'Checking if the first 3 characters of WksSheet.Name are numeric.
        If IsNumeric(Right(WksSheet.Name, 3)) Then
            
            'Increasing the size of VarReport.
            ReDim Preserve VarReport(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(VarReport, 2) + 1)
            
            'Reporting the name of WksSheet.
            VarReport(1, UBound(VarReport, 2)) = WksSheet.Name
            
            'Reporting the data of the cell specified (only 1 cell worth of data acceptable).
            VarReport(2, UBound(VarReport, 2)) = WksSheet.Range(StrAddress).Cells(1, 1)
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'Transposing the value in VarReport.
    VarReport = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VarReport)
    
    'Creating a new sheet.
    Set WksSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    
    'Focusing on the range where the report will be placed.
    With WksSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarReport, 1), UBound(VarReport, 2))
        
        'Formatting the range as text.
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        
        'Reporting the value of VarReport.
        .Value2 = VarReport
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

If you want to extract single or multiple cells from your sheet, try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubReportMultiCell()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim WksSheet As Worksheet
    Dim StrAddress As String
    Dim VarReport() As Variant
    Dim RngCell As Range
    Dim RngFocus As Range
    Dim DblCounter As Double
    
    'Settings.
    StrAddress = "C4:E4, H5"
    Set RngFocus = Range(StrAddress)
    
    'Redeclaring VarReport to accomodate "all" the data.
    ReDim VarReport(1 To RngFocus.Cells.Count + 1, 1 To 1)
    
    'Specifying the headers.
    VarReport(1, 1) = "Sheet"
    
    DblCounter = 2
    
    For Each RngCell In RngFocus
        
        VarReport(DblCounter, 1) = "Value in " & RngCell.Address(0, 0)
        
        DblCounter = DblCounter + 1
        
    Next
    
    'Covering each worksheet in ThisWorkbook.
    For Each WksSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        'Checking if the first 3 characters of WksSheet.Name are numeric.
        If IsNumeric(Right(WksSheet.Name, 3)) Then
            
            'Increasing the size of VarReport.
            ReDim Preserve VarReport(1 To UBound(VarReport, 1), 1 To UBound(VarReport, 2) + 1)
            
            'Reporting the name of WksSheet.
            VarReport(1, UBound(VarReport, 2)) = WksSheet.Name
            
            'Settings RngFocus.
            Set RngFocus = WksSheet.Range(StrAddress)
            DblCounter = 2
            
            'Reporting each data in RngFocus in VarReport.
            For Each RngCell In RngFocus
                
                VarReport(DblCounter, UBound(VarReport, 2)) = RngCell.Value2
                
                DblCounter = DblCounter + 1
                
            Next
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'Transposing the value in VarReport.
    VarReport = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VarReport)
    
    'Creating a new sheet.
    Set WksSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    
    'Focusing on the range where the report will be placed.
    With WksSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarReport, 1), UBound(VarReport, 2))
        
        'Formatting the range as text.
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        
        'Reporting the value of VarReport.
        .Value2 = VarReport
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

In both case, specify the address of your data in the line `StrAddress = "C4"` or `StrAddress = "C4:E4, H5"` of the setting section.

Note that the specified adressed here are hardcoded, but it is possible to make them dynamically determined. You can also make the user specify everytime what data he/she wants to extract using this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubReportThisRange()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim WksSheet As Worksheet
    Dim StrAddress As String
    Dim VarReport() As Variant
    Dim RngCell As Range
    Dim RngFocus As Range
    Dim DblCounter As Double
    Dim RngMyRange As Range
    
    'Settings.
    StrAddress = "C4:E4, H5"
    
    'Requesting the user to specify RngMyRange.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RngMyRange = Application.InputBox("Select the range from which you will extract the contracts data:", "Specify the range for the report", StrAddress, , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Checking if a range has not been specified.
    If RngMyRange Is Nothing Then
        
        'Terminating the macro.
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
    'Settings.
    StrAddress = RngMyRange.Address(0, 0)
    Set RngFocus = Range(StrAddress)
    
    'Redeclaring VarReport to accomodate "all" the data.
    ReDim VarReport(1 To RngFocus.Cells.Count + 1, 1 To 1)
    
    'Specifying the headers.
    VarReport(1, 1) = "Sheet"
    
    DblCounter = 2
    
    For Each RngCell In RngFocus
        
        VarReport(DblCounter, 1) = "Value in " & RngCell.Address(0, 0)
        
        DblCounter = DblCounter + 1
        
    Next
    
    'Covering each worksheet in ThisWorkboo.
    For Each WksSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        'Checking if the first 3 characters of WksSheet.Name are numeric.
        If IsNumeric(Right(WksSheet.Name, 3)) Then
            
            'Increasing the size of VarReport.
            ReDim Preserve VarReport(1 To UBound(VarReport, 1), 1 To UBound(VarReport, 2) + 1)
            
            'Reporting the name of WksSheet.
            VarReport(1, UBound(VarReport, 2)) = WksSheet.Name
            
            'Settings RngFocus.
            Set RngFocus = WksSheet.Range(StrAddress)
            DblCounter = 2
            
            'Reporting each data in RngFocus in VarReport.
            For Each RngCell In RngFocus
                
                VarReport(DblCounter, UBound(VarReport, 2)) = RngCell.Value2
                
                DblCounter = DblCounter + 1
                
            Next
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'Transposing the value in VarReport.
    VarReport = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VarReport)
    
    'Creating a new sheet.
    Set WksSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    
    'Focusing on the range where the report will be placed.
    With WksSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(VarReport, 1), UBound(VarReport, 2))
        
        'Formatting the range as text.
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        
        'Reporting the value of VarReport.
        .Value2 = VarReport
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

In this case, the line `StrAddress = "C4:E4, H5"` will specify the default range to be extracted which the user can either confirm, deny or modify. Remember that this last code can be regional-sensitive since the hardcoded address will either use a comma or a semicolon to separate diffent areas of the specified default range. You can probably make the code more resilient by placing these lines:

```
    'Correcting StrAddress for regional setting on list separator.
    StrAddress = Replace(Replace(StrAddress, ";", Application.International(xlListSeparator)), ",", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
```

between the  StrAddress setting line and the RngMyRange specifying line. Then again: since i can't test it and it's also probably an overkill, you most likely can ignore it.

Also: all these macros pre-set the range of the report as text in order (for example) to return the sheet's name as they are and not as numbers, but this will also (for example) returns date values as their serial counterparts.